# Слетела кодировка парсер python 2.7

Tags: python, парсер, python-2.x, python-2.7

Слетела кодировка, непонимает кириллицу код:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=ваш ключ&format=json&geocode=37.611347,55.760241')
r.status_code
r.headers['content-type']
r.encoding
r.text
r.json()
print(r.json())
```

При выводе `print r.text` ошибка:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 282-287: character maps to

Comment: В чем именно выражается "слетела кодировка"?

Comment: @insolor Выдает результат u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f, мне нужно Москва ул Пушкина это так для примера

Comment: Ну так это нормальный ответ. Просто вы как-то не так его выводите. Что у вас выведется если сделать `print r.text`?

Comment: @insolor ошибка:   File 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 282-287: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже разобрался. Как отмечается в этом ответе, ошибка кодирования происходит не от python, а от кодировки, которую использует консоль. Поэтому способ исправить это - запустить команду (в windows):

```
chcp 65001
```

который устанавливает кодировку UTF-8, а затем снова запускает программу. Или, если вы работали над pycharm, как я, перейдите в «Настройки»> «Редактор»> «Кодировки файлов» и соответственно установите кодировки IDE и Project.

Answer (score 0):

В этом запросе и не должно быть киррилицы, `ваш ключ` должно быть заменено на реальный API ключ вида `25831ee5-7a21-1234-a091-f80c70bed08c`.
А [вот](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/novye-pravila-dostupa-k-api-kart), что об это пишет сам яндекс.

P.S. не пытйтесь использовать предоставленный ключ, он предоставлен в демонстрационных целях и не является корректным API ключом.

Comment: я та получил ключ, в результате кодировка слетела где пишется на кириллице.

Comment: @user357670, что за каша у вас в голове, ничерта не понятно, научитесь выражать свои мысли! Какой-то набор буков!

Comment: @And Что здесь вам не понятно? У меня есть ключ для апи, но в результате кириллица слетела.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 282-287: character maps to` при выводе через `print` означает, что выводимые символы нельзя отобразить в кодировке, настроенной для консоли. В данном случае, судя по тексту ошибки, у вас для консоли настроена кодировка cp437 - это англоязычная кодировка, она не содержит кириллицы.

Проблема решается изменением кодировки консоли на кириллическую (стандартно - cp866). Это можно сделать отредактировав через regedit ключ реестра `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage`