# Вывод кириллицы на python 2.7 под Windows с английском локализацией

Tags: python, python-2.x, кодировка, python-2.7

У меня английский Windows. Возможно ли вывести в командную строку кириллицу?

Пример:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print('тест')
```

Результат:

```
╤ï╤ï╤ï
```

Comment: Поменять в реестре, как я вам уже писал в предыдущем вашем вопросе.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Слетела кодировка парсер python 2.7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075212/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-python-2-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже разобрался. Как отмечается в этом ответе, ошибка кодирования происходит не от python, а от кодировки, которую использует консоль. Поэтому способ исправить это - запустить команду (в windows):

```
chcp 65001
```

который устанавливает кодировку UTF-8, а затем снова запускает программу. Или, если вы работали над pycharm, как я, перейдите в «Настройки»> «Редактор»> «Кодировки файлов» и соответственно установите кодировки IDE и Project.